# How can I resolve connection error between spotfire7.6 servers

Tags: spotfire

I installed 4 Spotfire servers in my company which is in a cluster environment. I've got an error when I tried to install my 5th Spotfire server which is also on a cluster environment.  I went through the same procedure as previous when I installing the 5th Spotfire server.

I can log in to  Spotfire server but it shows a yellow warning saying I/O error and connection failure with other Spotfire servers. port shows as 0/0 in nodes and services.

Error notice is like this in the spotfire admin console

```
I/O error on POST request for "https://<server>:0/spotfire/nodemanager/ping/<id>":"
connect to <server>:443 connected time out;
nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTImeoutException:Connect to <server>:443 failed:connect timed out attempt communicate with node was unsucessful.
```

and in the server log, it shows like this

```
WARN [*Initialization*] jazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker:[Local][<id>][3.4]Could not find a maching address to start with! Picking one of non-loopback addresses.
WARN[*Initialization*] nodemanager.control.TopologyInspector:Exception when commnunicating with <server> I/O error on post request for <server>
```

by the way, All of them share same repository DB and I can telnet from my other Spotfire servers to my 5th Spotfire server.
I would be really grateful if you can give me a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: You may have better luck asking this question here: https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should raise a ticket with TIBCO Support. Spotfire gets a bit weird with more than four instances in a cluster. Support can help troubleshoot further for your specific needs.

but anecdotally, you are probably overdoing it. I've never seen a deployment with more than four servers in a cluster. you will be better off adding CPU and memory.

edit: just as aside, especially when posting about architecture issues like this (I assume this kind of question is OK on StackOverflow?), it's really helpful to include the version and hotfix of the product that you're working with. I don't think it matters for this question, but if you post more in the future, please do include this information :)

Comment: Niko, Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: It’s Spotfire 7.6. Actually we have 20 servers and want to connect through one cluster because we want to connect it to one Oracle DB. Is it possible to create several clusters using  One Data Base?

Comment: 20 servers??? This is anecdotal, but I work for TIBCO exclusively on Spotfire and I have never seen a 20-server cluster. I don’t know what your use case is but that sounds like way overkill. Disparate clusters can not connect to a single database as far as I’m aware but that’s a question for Support. Also there isn’t a good reason to use 7.6; it’s long past end of life and many years old at this point. 7.11 is the current LTS version; strongly recommend to upgrade before doing anything else.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for your quick reply.

Answer (score 2):

Checks for 5th Server

1. While configuring did you mentioned any alias that is not assigned to host.
2. While configuring you mentioned an IP address that is no longer valid.
3. Assuming you are using load balancer on top all servers. Then check the gateway ports

   3a. If required add ROUTE or update network gateway
4. You have enabled https on the server 5